# mongodb: how to check update or delete is successful

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

driver is pymongo;

question is: after issuing an update or delete operation, how to check data is successfully written to database? current method at hand seems to check `modified_count` and `deleted_count` value in the result; but operating on multiple documents needs to remember how many documents to update or delete and compare those numbers with those in result; this is cumbersome, and sometimes the number is not know beforehand (if the result tells me 5 documents are updated, does that mean there are only 5 documents matching the query and all updated, or there are 7 matching but 2 failed to update); in fact, the answer i want is a simple yes or no: yes means *all* data has been updated or deleted, and no means otherwise (either partial failure or total failure); are there any better ways to do this (such as checking exceptions, getting a numeric return value, etc.)?

Comment: The `UpdateResults` also has `matched_count`, why don't you use that?

Comment: @ArsenDavtyan how about delete results then? and comparing numbers is still not intuitive when examining if an operation has failed; returning an exit code or throwing an exception is better imho;